# Как передать в функцию массив строк?

Tags: c++

Как передать в функцию массив строк? Как в этой же функции изменять содержимое массива?

Comment: Если вопрос практический, лучше используйте vector. И везде, где можно, используйте STL. Это сэкономит кучу времени и избавит от неприятных ошибок.

Comment: @milillskegg: ... потому что [массивы -- это зло](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/arrays-are-evil.html)!

Comment: Проще передать ссылку на структуру внутри которой объявлен этот массив чем сам массив.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
...

void foo(string* array, int length){
  for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    array[i]=array[i]+ ".";
  }
}

...

string* array = new string[20];
foo(array, 20);
delete[] array;

...
```

Comment: если ТС имел в виду нативный массив, то, вероятно, и нативные строки.

Answer (score 6):

Если же речь идет о сишных строках, то вот:

```
...
void func(char* strings[], int c)
{
    for(unsigned i=0;i<c;i++) 
        cout<<strings[i]<<endl;
}
...
```

Где-то в `int main()`:

```
char* strings[5];

strings[0]="string1";
strings[1]="string2";
strings[2]="string3";
strings[3]="string4";
strings[4]="string5";

func(strings,5);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
void foo(std::vector<std::string>& vStrings)
{
   ...
}
```

Как-то так

Comment: @Andrey Buran, @VladD, но тут в функцию передается не МАССИВ СТРОК, а объект, контейнер шаблонного класса библиотеки STL. Поэтому, думаю, считать это решением задачи с передачей в функцию МАССИВА СТРОК не совсем верно. А так, на C++ это одно из самых рациональных и удобных решений.

Comment: В С++ char ** существует для совместимости с "C-legacy" кодом исключительно. Нет смысла использовать этот подход в новом коде. Надо либо использовать контейнеры и std::string, либо это С со веми вытекающими.
Задача поставлена неверно, как в анекдоте "Вы либо крест снимите, либо трусы наденьте"

Comment: @Andrey Buran, здесь @Asen прав, vector это **не массив**. Кстати, среди контейнеров есть [array](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/).

Также неизвестно, что имел в виду автор, говоря о строках string или char \*.

Comment: @avp, есть такая штука. Но в стандарт вошла только в С++11. До этого была частью boost. Написал его знаменитый Джосаттис, еще в конце 90-ых. Но это тоже не чистый массив, а обертка над массивом, хотя и очень тонкая. Vector - это тоже обертка над массивом, поскольку гарантировано, что содержимое вектора в памяти расположено последовательно. Так что vector - тоже своего рода массив.

Comment: @avp чёй-то он не массив? [] есть? есть. Арифметика указателей поддерживается? Поддерживается. Специально сделан вот для таких упёртых, кто пытается писать на C++ как на С (на самом деле нет). Про array на данном этапе развития C++11 давайте не будем.

Comment: @Andrey Buran, массив  - набор однотипных компонент (элементов), расположенных в памяти непосредственно друг за другом, доступ к которым осуществляется по индексу (индексам).( (с) Википедия). И [] тут не при чем. Для любого класса можно перегрузить operator[], но он от этого массивом не станет. Также можно написать итератор для доступа к самым разным типам данных (например, в boost::filesystem через итератор осуществляется последовательное чтение директории)

Comment: @mikillskegg: ну, элементы std::vector тоже лежат подряд, это гарантировано стандартом. А почему важно, что `operator []` перегружен? В Википедии такого требования нет. И да, я считаю, что если данные лежат подряд и индексируются целым числом -- то это массив. (Я бы ещё добавил требование, чтобы доступ был O(1). std::vector это тоже гарантирует.)

Comment: @Andrey Buran, @mikillskegg, @VladD, убедили **vector** это массив. Тогда, надо думать при resize адреса элементов могут измениться?

Comment: @avp: для вектора -- конечно, да. Для нативного массива -- нет, resize невозможен.

Comment: @VladD, это все понятно. 

Я то думал, что в реализации вектора что-то хитрое-эффективное придумано (по лени так и не смотрел исходник), а там значит все тривиально. 

Для красоты (в Си так не сделать, но может это и правильно) операция [] сделана. 

ОК. Всем спасибо!

Comment: @avp: угу, там всё тривиально. Вообще, std::vector -- довольно тонкая обёртка: контроль индексов при желании да realloc время от времени.

Comment: А разве в std::vector по стандарту элементы расположены не последовательно? И доступ к ним осуществляется не по индексу? Получается, что std::vector полностью соответствует Вашему определению.

Comment: @mikillskegg Вот не надо мне только википедией тыкать в лицо. Тем более что вы некорректно используете эту цитату (См ответ @VladID ) Моя мысль была исключительно в том что С-стиль не надо перетаскивать в другие языки.

Comment: Я соглашусь с тем, что требование насчет [] - опционально. Т.к. всегда можно перезагрузить его и использовать для самопального класса семантику массива. И не кипятитесь Вы так. Вроде адекватные люди...